# Optimal way to call a sequence of dates to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a stored procedure

```
EXEC demoProcedure @start='01-01-2019',@end = '02-01-2019'
```

The stored procedure takes the two date parameters, and runs for data between them. My question is I would like to have this procedure check multiple times for a multitude of date ranges. For example I would like to basically call:

```
EXEC demoProcedure @start='01-01-2019',@end = '02-01-2019';
EXEC demoProcedure @start='02-01-2019',@end = '03-01-2019';
....
EXEC demoProcedure @start='12-01-2019',@end = '01-01-2020'
```

Or effectively calling this stored procedure once for every month. In the past, I have messed around with creating a temp date table:

```
;WITH DateTable AS
(
SELECT row = 1, date = '2019-01-01'
UNION ALL

    SELECT row + 1, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, date)
    FROM DateTable
    WHERE row + 1 <= 7
)
SELECT *
FROM DateTable
```

Which effectively returns Jan first for the past 7 years. Is there a way to easily combine these two to call the stored procedure once for each set of dates? I.e. call it for start=row(1),end=row(2); start=row(2),end=row(3);.... to the end of row? Or is there an easier way to set all of this up. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you fix the procedure to group the results by month? Then you only need to call it once and not over and over.

Comment: Can you describe why you need to call it separately for each month?  Also, does the SP return a dataset, and do you need to use it in some form after calling the SP?

Comment: @remh . . . Really, if you are calling this in code, then running a while loop 12 times seems simpler -- and safer -- than modifying the underlying procedure.  I suspect you have some other motive, such as returning a single result set.  Perhaps you can handle that by inserting into a temporary table.

Comment: What would make one way "easier" than another?

Comment: What is your end goal here? To copy the data into Excel or some other software? Why do you need 12 separate result sets instead of 1?

Comment: @SeanLange You know what... That makes a ton of sense hahaha. Sometimes the easiest solutions are right in front of you. Thanks! Think I just got a bit to much into trying to figure out some other way haha